# Any li-ion battery metric or test that could correlate with its past usage?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I am trying to find any metric or test method that I could use to get information regarding a battery's past usage.

Suppose a battery 'A' has been used in good conditions in the past and battery 'B' has been used relatively poorer in the past.

Is there any test I can perform on a battery cycler and use that data to correlate its usage history?

Any research article would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Compare its capacity and ESR with its original spec.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can tell the difference between a battery that has been used carefully for a long period of time and a battery that has been abused for a short period of time. The degradation of the battery will be very similar.

In both cases the capacity of the battery will decrease and the ESR will increase. But there is also manufacturing variation, and if you don't know the actual starting values of those parameters you won't know how much the battery has changed, much less why.

In other words, you can estimate the present condition of a battery fairly well but it is unlikely that you can reconstruct its history.